Start Wireguard Interface on Boot
I have a VPN subscription and Wireguard CLI installed on macOS Ventura (v 13.6.5).
I have followed this link to automatically start a Wireguard interface on boot, but it gives me an error:
Warning: `/private/etc/wireguard/se-sto-wg-014.conf' is world accessible
[#] wireguard-go utun
[+] Interface for se-sto-wg-014 is utun4
[#] wg setconf utun4 /dev/fd/63
[#] ifconfig utun4 inet 10.65.194.168/32 10.65.194.168 alias
[#] ifconfig utun4 up
[#] route -q -n add -inet 0.0.0.0/1 -interface utun4
route: writing to routing socket: File exists
[#] route -q -n add -inet 128.0.0.0/1 -interface utun4
route: writing to routing socket: File exists
[#] route -q -n add -inet 185.195.233.68 -gateway 192.168.1.1
[#] networksetup -getdnsservers USB 10/100/1000 LAN
[#] networksetup -getsearchdomains USB 10/100/1000 LAN
[#] networksetup -getdnsservers Thunderbolt Bridge
[#] networksetup -getsearchdomains Thunderbolt Bridge
[#] networksetup -getdnsservers Wi-Fi
[#] networksetup -getsearchdomains Wi-Fi
[#] networksetup -setdnsservers Wi-Fi 100.64.0.55
[#] networksetup -setsearchdomains Wi-Fi Empty
[#] networksetup -setdnsservers USB 10/100/1000 LAN 100.64.0.55
[#] networksetup -setsearchdomains USB 10/100/1000 LAN Empty
[#] networksetup -setdnsservers Thunderbolt Bridge 100.64.0.55
[#] networksetup -setsearchdomains Thunderbolt Bridge Empty
[+] Backgrounding route monitor
[#] mullvad-upgrade-tunnel -wg-interface utun4
unable to connect ephemeral peer, rpc error: code = Unknown desc = unable to service request at this time
[#] rm -f /var/run/wireguard/utun4.sock
[#] rm -f /var/run/wireguard/se-sto-wg-014.name
[#] route -q -n delete -inet 185.195.233.68
Warning: `/private/etc/wireguard/se-sto-wg-014.conf' is world accessible
[#] wireguard-go utun
[+] Interface for se-sto-wg-014 is utun0
[#] wg setconf utun0 /dev/fd/63
[#] ifconfig utun0 inet 10.65.194.168/32 10.65.194.168 alias
[#] ifconfig utun0 up
[#] route -q -n add -inet 0.0.0.0/1 -interface utun0
[#] route -q -n add -inet 128.0.0.0/1 -interface utun0
[#] route -q -n add -inet 185.195.233.68 127.0.0.1 -blackhole
[#] networksetup -getdnsservers USB 10/100/1000 LAN
[#] networksetup -getsearchdomains USB 10/100/1000 LAN
[#] networksetup -getdnsservers Thunderbolt Bridge
[#] networksetup -getsearchdomains Thunderbolt Bridge
[#] networksetup -getdnsservers Wi-Fi
[#] networksetup -getsearchdomains Wi-Fi
[#] networksetup -setdnsservers Wi-Fi 100.64.0.55
[#] networksetup -setsearchdomains Wi-Fi Empty
[#] networksetup -setdnsservers USB 10/100/1000 LAN 100.64.0.55
[#] networksetup -setsearchdomains USB 10/100/1000 LAN Empty
[#] networksetup -setdnsservers Thunderbolt Bridge 100.64.0.55
[#] networksetup -setsearchdomains Thunderbolt Bridge Empty
[+] Backgrounding route monitor
[#] mullvad-upgrade-tunnel -wg-interface utun0
unable to connect ephemeral peer, context deadline exceeded
[#] rm -f /var/run/wireguard/utun0.sock
[#] rm -f /var/run/wireguard/se-sto-wg-014.name
[#] route -q -n delete -inet 185.195.233.68

When I run sudo wg-quick up se-sto-wg-014 from the Terminal, the VPN connection gets active.
How can I start the VPN automatically on every boot ?

Is this the content of opt/homebrew/var/log/wireguard.err?

Yes, the error block in the post is from /opt/homebrew/var/log/wireguard.err
